# How to calculate revenue from last 12 months group by age

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the `FACT_SALES` and `DIM_SELLERS` tables defined below, I want a query that returns only the seller within each age cohort who has the highest trailing twelve months revenue (<30 days, 31-90 days, 91-120 days, >120 days).

```
Age = elapsed time to - date since seller start day
```

Table FACT_SALES

```
dim_seller_sk BIGINT,
sale_day DATE,
net_units INT,
total_sales_revenue FLOAT
```

Table DIM_SELLERS

```
dim_seller_sk BIGINT,
seller_name VARCHAR(250),
seller_start_day DATE`
```

I am trying to get the age like this :

```
WITH ages AS
(
    SELECT
        seller_name,
        ROUND(DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), seller_start_day), 0) AS age
    FROM 
        dbo.dim_sellers
),
cte2 AS
(
    SELECT
        ages.seller_name,
        CASE
           WHEN ages.age <= 30 THEN '<= 30 days'
           WHEN ages.age >= 31 AND ages.age <= 90 THEN '31-90 days'
           WHEN ages.age >= 91 AND ages.age <= 120 THEN '91-120 days'
           WHEN ages.age >= 120 THEN '> 120 days'
        END AS age_category
    FROM 
        ages
)
SELECT
    'revenue logic',
    cte2.seller_name,
    cte2.age_category
FROM
    dbo.FACT_SALES, cte2
GROUP BY
    cte2.seller_name, cte2.age_category
```

How do I calculate the revenue for this? As I have got the `age_category`.
Can I select from table and a cte in single select statement?

Missing part of puzzle is revenue logic. Can I get some hints on how can I achieve that.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need a proper `JOIN`?

```
with ages as (
      select s.*,
             ROUND(DATEDIFF(day, getdate(),seller_start_day), 0) as age
      from dbo.dim_sellers s
     ),
     cte2 as (
      select ages.*,
             (case when ages.age <= 30 then '<=30 days'
                   when ages.age <= 90 then '31-90 days'
                   when ages.age <= 120 then '91-120 days'
                   else '>120 days'
              end
             ) as age_category
       from ages
      )
select 'revenue logic', cte2.seller_name, cte2.age_category,
       sum(s.total_sales_revenue)
from dbo.FACT_SALES s join
     cte2
     on cte2.dim_seller_sk = s.dim_seller_sk
where s.sale_day >= dateadd(month, -12, getdate())
group by cte2.seller_name, cte2.age_category;
```

Comment: ohhh gort it. this join would work. I just wanted to know how to calculate that revenue for trailing 12 months in this scenario

Comment: @PriyalChaudhari . . . You absolute *do* need a `join`.  The question is only whether that is *all* you need.

Comment: so join was one part that i was missing i realized my mistake. I am missing the revenue logic as well

Comment: Look careful at this proposed answer that adds a revenue sum to aggregate query (though it has no column alias). And maybe placeholder *revenue_logic* can be removed.